# Colors and buttons change behavior when tinting iPhone navigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I was wondering why everything stops behaving as it should when I do something like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

All my buttons on the navigationBar are now black regardless of style, like this one below, it should turn up as a blue button:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(editTrip)];
```

It does not, it is just black.

The slight change/effect in the button when tapped is also gone?

Is there a way to change the color of the navigationBar and maybe even the UIbarButtonItems without somehow ruining standard behavior?

This is really strange. I just checked with the Apple "Remote" app, it has the black navigation bar and a blue "Done" button for leaving the "help" section.

Do I really have to build everything custom to achieve this?

Thanks for any help given:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Interface Builder, change the Style of the Navigation Bar to Black Opaque or Black Translucent and leave the tint alone.  This will give you a black bar with the standard blue buttons.

I'm sure the way to do this in code without Interface Builder, is by setting the `barStyle` property to `UIBarStyleBlack` or `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`, but I haven't done it that way.

Comment: Hi mahboudz
Thanks I'll try that right away. I was wondering if the tint where being applied to every subview, it seems like it:)
I'll be setting these thing in code so will just get back with the results.

Comment: Perfect mahboudz!
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

Get's me both the black look and the right colored buttons:)
Thanks again!